# How to add gradient overlay to the <img> element with css?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm making html markup of this [page section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK8B3.png). As you can see here it is three images. When I set my mouse cursor on one of them the image is shifted and becomes overlayed with linear-gradient. The code of images

**Code**

```css
.image_row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image_row img:hover,
.image_row img:focus {
  transform: translate(-9px, -9px);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px #95e1d3;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_row">
  <img src="image-1" height="250" width="380" />
  <img src="image-2" height="250" width="380" />
  <img src="image-3" height="250" width="380" />
</div>
```

**My problem is that I don't how to make gradient overlay for the image.** I tried the follow code, but it didn't bring any effect:

```
.image_row img:hover,
.image_row img:focus{
transform: translate(-9px, -9px);
box-shadow: 10px 10px #95e1d3;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(252,227,138) 0%, rgb(243,129,129) 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(252,227,138) 0%, rgb(243,129,129) 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(252,227,138) 0%, rgb(243,129,129) 100%);
mix-blend-mode: normal;
opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a pseudo-element with CSS that overlays the images and get shown on hover/focus which also has the gradient effect on it.

I modified your Code into the following example:

```css
.image_row {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .image_row img:hover,
    .image_row img:focus {
      transform: translate(-9px, -9px);
      box-shadow: 10px 10px #95e1d3;
    }
    
    img {
      display: block;
    }

    .image {
      position: relative;
    }

    .image::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .image:hover,
    .image:focus {
      transform: translate(-9px, -9px);
      box-shadow: 10px 10px #95e1d3;
    }

    .image:hover::before,
    .image:focus::before {
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(252, 227, 138) 0%, rgb(243, 129, 129) 100%);
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(252, 227, 138) 0%, rgb(243, 129, 129) 100%);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(252, 227, 138) 0%, rgb(243, 129, 129) 100%);
      mix-blend-mode: overlay;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="image_row">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/380x250" height="250" width="380" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/380x250" height="250" width="380" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/380x250" height="250" width="380" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice solution. The only thing to change here is gradient parameters. To follow psd prototype we need to use mix-blend-mode: normal with opacity:0,9.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using div instead of img tag.
something like that might work for you:

```css
.image_row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.image_row div:hover,
.image_row div:focus {
  transform: translate(-9px, -9px);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px #95e1d3;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:hover:after {
  opacity: .5;
}

.red_overlay:after {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(252, 227, 138) 0%, rgb(243, 129, 129) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(252, 227, 138) 0%, rgb(243, 129, 129) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( 90deg, rgb(252, 227, 138) 0%, rgb(243, 129, 129) 100%);
}

.box {
  width: 380px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 10px;
  ;
}
```

```html
<div class=image_row>
  <div style="background-image:url(images/1.jpg)" height="250" width="380" class="box overlay red_overlay">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. This code can be use used with little modifications to achieve needed effect and it solves gradient-overlay problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for img tag use a background: linear-gradient on a parent div, that worked for me:

```
<

div class="home-hero-two-image">
<img src="./resources/images/homepage/mobile-header-img.jpg" />
</div>

.home-hero-two-image {
    transform: scaleX(1);
                }

.home-hero-two-image ::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    z-index: 10;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgb(54, 62, 75);
    background: linear-gradient(
    0deg,
    rgba(54, 62, 75, 0) 51%,
    rgba(enter code here54, 62, 75, 0.8855917366946778) 100%
   );
}
```